# ie6 ul.li hover

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

i know that ie6 can only do hover on a href element. but i do not need a href element.

i have ul.li element like below

```
ul.testclass li {
    display: inline-block;


}



ul.testclass li:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;


}
```

it work on all browsers except ie6.  any workaround to make it work in ie6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common workaround is [using a `htc` file](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html).

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use something like [ie7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)

Answer (score 1):

There's a variety of ways you can do it. The simplest is probably to use [Dean Edwards' wonderful IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).